# Contact Form 7 как скрыть чекбокс согласия для зарегистрированных пользователей?

Tags: html

Они уже соглашались с правилами при регистрации, как не показывать им этот чекбокс?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для скрытия чекбокса согласия в Contact Form 7 для зарегистрированных пользователей, вы можете использовать условную логику с помощью плагина Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields. Вот как это можно сделать:

Установите и активируйте плагин Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields в вашем WordPress-сайте, если вы еще не сделали этого.

Откройте страницу редактирования вашей формы в разделе Contact в административной панели WordPress.

Добавьте чекбокс согласия к вашей форме, как обычно.

Затем добавьте еще одно поле, которое будет использоваться для проверки статуса пользователя. Вы можете использовать поле типа "текст" и внести в него значение, например, "зарегистрирован". Это поле будет помогать определить, является ли пользователь зарегистрированным.

Теперь настройте условия отображения чекбокса согласия. Нажмите на вкладку "Настройки условий" на странице редактирования формы. Здесь вы можете создать новое условие. Например:

Если [user_status] равен "зарегистрирован", то покажите чекбокс согласия.
Закройте окно настройки условий и сохраните форму.

Теперь, когда зарегистрированный пользователь заполнит форму, поле [user_status] должно быть автоматически заполнено значением "зарегистрирован". Это активирует условие, и чекбокс согласия будет отображаться только для незарегистрированных пользователей.

Убедитесь, что вы правильно настроили поле [user_status] в зависимости от статуса пользователя на вашем сайте, чтобы условия корректно работали.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с помощью рекомендованного плагина, правда немного иначе:

С помощью плагина Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension, я создал скрытое динамическое поле отслеживающее имя текущего пользователя, выглядело это примерно так:

[dynamic_hidden dynamic_hidden-714 "CF7_get_current_user"]

После этого с помощью рекомендованного выше плагина Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields, я создал групповой тег и завернул в него свой чекбокс, получилось так:

[group group-714][acceptance acceptance-357 default:on] Согласие на обработку данных

[/group]

И после этого задал условие при котором эта группа показывается, если мой динамический скрытый тег равен(equals) пустому полю(не пишите там ничего). Если пользователь зарегистрирован, то имя отдаётся и чекбокс не показывается. Не забудьте сделать чекбокс включенным по умолчанию, иначе форма работать не будет.

Comment: Отлично, рад что Ваша задача была решена!)))